# How do I take values from html page and insert into sql table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

I want to take all values from this link
`http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/indices/nifty_50_companies.cms`

and want to put those `NIFTY 50` companies `companyname` and `LTP` into `sql table`.

please help me give me some threads

I want use c# ,asp.net :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Searcharoo** has a class called the **HtmlDocument**. You can split the downloaded html content(use System.Net.WebClient to download the document from the url) into metatitle, metadescription, metakeywords and content(words).

You can find the searcharoo download here(it is open source)

http://www.searcharoo.net/SearcharooV7/

Answer (score 2):

Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to get the values from the HTML page.

Find tutorials from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack) on how to use HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a table in SQL..

You may do it like this:

1. Download the page
2. Parse its content
3. [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) the values in the table